# Crossed Categories

Tags: category

I'm currently planning a major migration from (1) a proprietary e-commerce system to (2) Magento.

On (1), we have multiple crossable categories :

Root category : Clothing

- Category 1 : Women
- Category 2 : Shoes
- Category 3 : Adidas

We currently have access to these landing-pages, thanks to the faceted navigation :

- /clothing/women/shoes/adidas
- /clothing/shoes/adidas
- /clothing/shoes
- /clothing/adidas

One interesting thing : if we are on **/clothing/adidas**, and we want to filter by "shoes", the link will be **/clothing/shoes/adidas** - not **/clothing/adidas/shoes**.

The question is : is there any way to handle this whole system in (2) Magento ?

I tried to play with the categories, subcategories and attributes, but without finding a solution.

Comment: By "the link" do you mean the current URL, or the links of the products on the page (e.g. /clothing/shoes/adidas/some_shoe)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out URL rewrites under **Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management**. At least two kinds of rewrites are applicable to your use case:

1. You can add a redirect from `/clothing/adidas/shoes` to `/clothing/shoes/adidas`.
2. You can add a non-redirecting rewrite that shows a certain category when you visit `/clothing/shoes/adidas`.

Number 2 is handled automatically by Magento through the `URL key` option on the category configuration page, so chances are you can already find such a non-redirecting rewrite among your URL rewrites. Automatic rewrites have `type` set to `System`.